# Most efficient way to print text file to stdout to put through data processing pipeline using Shell

Tags: bash, performance

I have a problem when processing text files in a data processing pipeline in Shell and Python.

What is a better solution to print text files to `stdout` to put through a data processing pipeline (using `perl` in the script `tokenise.sh` and `python`)?

My current script in Shell works fine except that it does not output the last line in a `txt` file. I'm not sure if I should use `cat` or `echo` or something else (instead of `while IFS= read line ...`) for better performance.

```sh
for f in path/to/dir/*.txt; do
  while IFS= read line
  do
    echo $line 
  done < "$f" \
  | tokenize.sh \
  | python clean.py \
  >> $f.clean.txt 
  rm $f 
  mv $f.clean.txt $f 
done
```

I tried using `awk` as below and it seems to work well.

```sh
for f in path/to/dir/*.txt; do
  awk '{ print }' $f \
  | tokenize.sh \
  | python clean.py \
  >> $f.clean.txt 
  rm $f 
  mv $f.clean.txt $f 
done
```

Comment: This is arguably too broad. A single question per question, please.

Comment: The `while read` loop serves no useful purpose, and contains a quoting bug, and wild massively slow you down. You want simply `for f in path/to/dir/*.txt; do tokenize.sh <"$f" | python`...

Comment: @tripleee Thank you so much for your comment! I will split the question 2 to ask in another thread. I tried your suggestion but the script does not stop running after the step `python clean.py`. I tried using `awk` and it seems to work well. I just do not feel safe of the solution because I'm very new to Shell script.

Comment: @tripleee Oh I'm so sorry I tried your solution but I missed the `<"f"`part :(.

Comment: note:I think it is generally  a bad idea to delete the input file. (instead, you could compress it, or move it to another directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for f in path/to/dir/*.txt; do

  # - while loop replaced by "<"
  # - $f quoted to handle special chars. <<< IMPORTANT!
  # - is ">>" really necessary?
  #   seems to have a side effect, if "$f.clean.txt" already exists

  tokenize.sh < "$f" | python clean.py > "$f.clean.txt"

  # "mv" includes "rm" and && file "$f" exists always
  # rm $f
  mv "$f.clean.txt" "$f"

done
```

Comment: Maybe still highlight the significance of the quoting fixes. See [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)